# How to disable all not checked checkbox?

Tags: javascript, html

In the html file there is a lot of checkbox element. If 3 of them are checked, then the rest should be disabled, until one of the checked checkbox are again unchecked.
Here is the JS code and HTML

```js
$('.check [type=checkbox]').change(function(){
  var checkNum = $('.check [type=checkbox]');
  var checkedNum = $('.check [type=checkbox]:checked').length;
  
  if(checkedNum >= 3){
  for(i=0;i<checkNum.length; i++){
  if(checkNum[i].prop('checked')==false){
  (checkNum[i].prop('disabled')==true))
  }
  }
  }
})
```

```html
<label class="check">
  <input type="checkbox">
  <div>Select</div>
</label>

<label class="check">
  <input type="checkbox">
  <div>Select</div>
</label>

<label class="check">
  <input type="checkbox">
  <div>Select</div>
</label>

<label class="check">
  <input type="checkbox">
  <div>Select</div>
</label>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need any loop here. If the condition is `true` then you can simply target the not `checked` check boxes to set the `disabled` attribute to true. If the condition is `false` then set the attribute to `false` to all the check boxes:

```js
$('.check [type=checkbox]').change(function(){
  var checkNum = $('.check [type=checkbox]');
  var checkedNum = $('.check [type=checkbox]:checked');
  
  if(checkedNum.length >= 3){
    $('.check [type=checkbox]:not(:checked)').attr('disabled',true);
  }
  else{
    checkNum.attr('disabled',false);
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label class="check">
  <input type="checkbox">
  <div>Select</div>
</label>

<label class="check">
  <input type="checkbox">
  <div>Select</div>
</label>

<label class="check">
  <input type="checkbox">
  <div>Select</div>
</label>

<label class="check">
  <input type="checkbox">
  <div>Select</div>
</label>
```

Comment: Thanks! interesting, I wrote the code exactly as you, but by me I need also this: $('.check [type=checkbox]:checked').attr('disabled',false); Otherwise I can't uncheck the checked checkbox.

Comment: @venndi, the code you have written is not *exactly* as mine, there is a for loop in your code. also there is some syntax error in your code. Also, I am not sure why do you need extra code as the above solution easily allows to check/uncheck which ever you want:)

Comment: haha sorry, my english isn't the best, so maybe my answer wasn't clear. I mean I changed my code to yours, and I also got a problem, but it was my fault of course, I forgot one colon, I wrote like this $('.check [type=checkbox]:not(checked)').attr('disabled',true); and that was the reason why had I problem :) Thanks for the help!